# Set background color for whole pane in terminal using python Rich library

Tags: python, terminal, colors

how do I use rich (https://rich.readthedocs.io/) to clear the screen with a background color, such that the entire screen is solid that color, and when I print lines, their background colors stand out against the overall background? I'm already using console.print(..., style="white on red") sorts of things to color individual lines, but that doesn't color after the end of the line, which stays the terminal's background color.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a workable way to do it is with https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/panel.html:

```
from rich import print
from rich.panel import Panel
print(Panel("Hello, [on red]World![/on red]", style="on grey0"))
```

[image: hello world in a 3 line panel, with the word world highlighted red]

unfortunately this has a black border around it which I'd like to get rid of, but it works well enough for my purposes. It also doesn't automatically match terminal height and keep it that way, but that's fine as I'm just printing out some stuff and want the background contrasted. I hope this answer helps others figure out which api did the job :)